# Get index of objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

I am trying to find the index of each object in my array.

```
   public class MonsterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Monster [] ma = new Monster[3];
        ma[0] = new Vampire();
        ma[1] = new Dragon();
        ma[2] = new Monster();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println(ma[x].getClass());
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(ma[x]).indexOf(x));
            ma[x].frighten(x);

        }

    }

}
```

Am I using the `java.util.Arrays.asList(ARRAY).indexOf(element)` method here correct? (Well I am obviously not because the output is incorrect.

Comment: What does `Arrays.asList(..)` do? What does `indexOf(..)` do? (Go see.)

Answer (score 1):

You already have it - it's `x`. You don't need to use such a specific functions to get something you already have.

```
public class MonsterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Monster [] ma = new Monster[3];
        ma[0] = new Vampire();
        ma[1] = new Dragon();
        ma[2] = new Monster();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println(ma[x].getClass());
            System.out.println(x);
            ma[x].frighten(x);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what your code does:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(ma[x])
```

creates a List containing **exactly 1** element: `ma[x]`.

Perhaps you are trying to do this instead, to create a list of all `Monster`s in array `ma`:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(ma)
```

---

```
/*...*/.indexOf(x)
```

This tries to find a `Integer` in the list. (auto boxing of your loop variable). This obviously returns `-1` since there are no `Integer`s (only `Monster`s) in the list.

To get a result != -1 you have to pass a `Monster` as argument to `indexOf`, e.g. something like this:

```
/*...*/.indexOf(ma[x])
```

(which will return `x` btw., if you use my both modifications above and none of your monsters are equal (using `equals`) and `equals` is reflexive, which is the case if you don't override it)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(ma[x]).indexOf(x));
```

You are specifying an index where you shouldn't in the parameter of the asList method. Instead try this:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(ma).indexOf(x));
```

Comment: This results in the same output.

Comment: Yes, cause you are correctly giving the list as an argument `ma` , but look for the index of object of type Integer and not of type Monster. If you want to rely on this approach, use `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(ma).indexOf(ma[x]));`